Matplotlib - size of 3D subplot within figure
I want to create a 3D plot of some data. First, I download the data:
# Import the libraries

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the data

start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()

assets = {'DGS3MO': '3m', 'DGS6MO': '6m', 'DGS1': '1y', 'DGS2': '2y', 'DGS3': '3y', 'DGS5': '5y', 'DGS7': '7y', 'DGS10': '10y', 'DGS20': '20y', 'DGS30': '30y'}
df_yields = pdr.DataReader(list(assets.keys()), 'fred', start, end)
df_yields.rename(columns=assets, inplace=True)
df_yields = df_yields.dropna(how='any')

Then, I create the 3D plot:
# Create 3D plot

dates = np.array([x.toordinal() for x in df_yields.index])
maturities = np.array([3/12, 6/12, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(dates, maturities)
Z = df_yields.values.T

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(0.9, 0.5, 0.4))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cmap='Blues', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Maturity (Y)')
ax.set_zlabel('Yield (%)')

years = np.arange(start.year, end.year + 1)
selected_years = np.linspace(start.year, end.year, 5, dtype=int)
ax.set_xticks([datetime.date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() for year in selected_years])
ax.set_xticklabels(selected_years)
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 5
ax.zaxis.labelpad = -1

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=100, top=0.95, bottom=0.05)

This is the output:

There are two things I would want to fix:

The fact that the right hand size of the plot is cut by the figure edge
Reduce the wide margins at the top and bottom (and ideally make also those on the left and right as tight as possible).

I have tried for a very long time to tackle both, but I haven't made any progress. Any advice?

Setting the limits of the plots' axes will definitely make it tighter. You can also use plt.tight_layout() which should adjust the margins to be tight automatically.
So, when incorporating these into your code:
dates = np.array([x.toordinal() for x in df_yields.index])
maturities = np.array([3/12, 6/12, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(dates, maturities)
Z = df_yields.values.T

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(0.9, 0.5, 0.4))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cmap='Blues', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Maturity (Y)')
ax.set_zlabel('Yield (%)')

years = np.arange(start.year, end.year + 1)
selected_years = np.linspace(start.year, end.year, 5, dtype=int)
ax.set_xticks([datetime.date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() for year in selected_years])
ax.set_xticklabels(selected_years)
ax.set_ylim(0,max(maturities))
ax.set_xlim(min(dates), max(dates))
ax.set_zlim(0, max(df_yields.max()))
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 5
ax.zaxis.labelpad = -1

plt.tight_layout()

#plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, right=0.7, top=0.8, bottom=0.05)

plt.show()

together with the mentioned plt.tight_layout() the margins will be significantly smaller, at least on the sides and the bottom:

If you want them even tighter, I can recommend to use plotly:
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# import the data
start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()

assets = {'DGS3MO': '3m', 'DGS6MO': '6m', 'DGS1': '1y', 'DGS2': '2y', 'DGS3': '3y', 'DGS5': '5y', 'DGS7': '7y', 'DGS10': '10y', 'DGS20': '20y', 'DGS30': '30y'}
df_yields = pdr.DataReader(list(assets.keys()), 'fred', start, end)
df_yields.rename(columns=assets, inplace=True)
df_yields = df_yields.dropna(how='any')


dates = np.array([x.toordinal() for x in df_yields.index])
maturities = np.array([3/12, 6/12, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(dates, maturities)
Z = df_yields.values.T

# plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=dates, y=maturities, colorscale='Blues')])

fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='Date',
        yaxis_title='Maturity (Years)',
        zaxis_title='Yield (%)',
        xaxis=dict(tickvals=[datetime.date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() for year in np.linspace(start.year, end.year, 5, dtype=int)],
                   ticktext=[str(year) for year in np.linspace(start.year, end.year, 5, dtype=int)]),
    ),
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=40, b=0),  # Tight margins
    title='3D Curve'
)

fig.show()

which results in:


For me the first method does not work: the axis limits have no effect, and tight_layout just returns a warning with no effect: /var/folders/23/cbqpy2xd71l05c7yvx1xp4hw0000gn/T/ipykernel_12107/738210649.py:31: UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The left and right margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all Axes decorations.
plt.tight_layout()

I think in your figure the margins are tighter just because you changed the angle.

Yes, that's possible that plt.tight_layout() won't work when limiting the axes. To me, it's obvious though that the margins are smaller. Look at the bottom and the right side of the two snippets for example. That's not the angle.

Would you be able to paste the full code?

I edited my answer, you can see the code I used for creating the plot now.
